# Perl script to count the number of control-A characters per line in a file

Tags: perl

I need to count the number of control A characters in each line of a file and I'm completely stumped because I don't know what the regex for a control A character would be.

Comment: Aside from using the character itself in quotes, each of the following produce a string that consists of that character: `"\cA"`, `"\001"`, `"\x01"`, `"\x{01}"`, `"\N{U+0001}"`, `chr(1)`, `pack('C',1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

counting number occurrences of ^A per line (as a perl one-liner):

```
perl -ne '{print tr/\cA//, $/}' file
```

counting total number occurrences of ^A:

```
perl -ne '{$c += tr/\cA//}END{print $c, $/}' file
```

(edit: fixed typo)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
s/[^\001]//g;
$count += length;
END {print "$count\n"}
```

Or, for a count of each line:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
s/[^\001]//g;
print length, "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$_ = '^Axyz^Apqr';
$match= tr/^A/^A/;
```

will give

```
$match=2;
```

In Gvim you can insert control A by hitting  Ctrl+v followed by Ctrl+a

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, didn't think of using `tr`:

```
perl -ne '{print s/\cA//g, $/}'
```

The `s/to/from/g` returns the number of times a string is replaced. `tr/x/y/` returns the number of characters *replaced*. In this circumstance, `tr/x/y/` will work, but it you're looking for a string and not a single character, you'd run into trouble.

I originally though `m/regex/g` would work, but it turns out that it only returns a `1` or a `0`.  Drats.

Comment: m/regex/g *in list context* works. Or rather, counting the matches it returns.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to count the occurrences of byte 01. It can be represented in both tr/// and m// a number of ways, including `\cA` and `\x01`.

```
perl -nE'say "$.: ", tr/\cA//' file

perl -nE'say "$.: " . ( ()=/\cA/g )' file
```